# Web scraper for a webpage article

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am a beginner in Python and have just coded a simple web scraper for a webpage article, output to a text file, using `BeautifulSoup` and `List`.

The code is working fine, but I'm wondering if anybody would know a more efficient way to achieve the same.

```
import requests
page = requests.get('https://www.msn.com/en-sg/money/topstories/10-top-stocks-of-2017/ar-BBGgEyA?li=AA54rX&ocid=spartandhp')

# 2. Parsing the page using BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')

# 3. Write the context to a text file
all_p_tags = soup.findAll('p') # Put all <p> and their text into a list
number_of_tags = len(all_p_tags) # No of <p>?

x=0
with open('filename.txt', mode='wt', encoding='utf-8') as file:
    title = soup.find('h1').text.strip() # Write the <header>
    file.write(title)
    file.write('\n')
    for x in range(number_of_tags):
        word = all_p_tags[x].get_text() # Write the content by referencing each item in the list
        file.write(word)
        file.write('\n')
    file.close()
```

Comment: Is there a reason you want to make this "efficient"? And that `file.close()` is unnecessary, js.

Answer (score 1):

There are at least three things that may help to make the code more efficient:

- switch to [`lxml` instead of `html.parser`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#installing-a-parser) (requires `lxml` to be installed)
- use a [`SoupStrainer`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#parsing-only-part-of-a-document) to parse only the relevant part of the document
- you can switch to `http` instead of `https`. While this would bring the security aspect down, you would avoid overhead of SSL handshaking, encryption etc - I've noticed the execution time difference locally, try it out

Improved code:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup, SoupStrainer

page = requests.get('http://www.msn.com/en-sg/money/topstories/10-top-stocks-of-2017/ar-BBGgEyA?li=AA54rX&ocid=spartandhp')

parse_only = SoupStrainer("body")
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'lxml', parse_only=parse_only) 

with open('filename.txt', mode='wt', encoding='utf-8') as file:
    title = soup.find('h1').text.strip()
    file.write(title + ' \n')

    for p_tag in soup.select('p') :
        file.write(p_tag.get_text() + '\n')
```

Note that I've also removed the unused variables and imports.

Btw, if it weren't for the `title`, we could've pinpointed `SoupStrainer` to `p` elements only - might've improved performance even more.

Answer (score 0):

```
#libraries always at top, at least if they are not conditional imported
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup   



 base_url = 'https://www.msn.com/en-sg/money/topstories/\
 10-top-stocks-of-2017/ar-BBGgEyA?li=AA54rX&ocid=spartandhp'

 page = requests.get(base_url)
 content = page.content 

# 2. Parsing the page using BeautifulSoup
#removed pandas as you are not using it here.   

soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')   

# 3. Write the context to a text file
all_p_tags = soup.findAll('p') # Put all <p> and their text into a list
#you don't need to count then   

#not initializer needed, remove x = 0   

with open('filename.txt', mode='wt', encoding='utf-8') as file:
    title = soup.find('h1').text.strip() # Write the <header>
    file.write(title + ' \n')
    for p in all_p_tags:
        file.write(p.get_text()+ ' \n') 

    #files open with a 'with' statement doens't have to be manually closet
```